# Passing multiple object to axios post request but it's not working

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios

I am trying to pass 3 objects the first is of type Text and the 2 others are of type MultipartFile to my back-end controller but it's not working, it's always empty field I don't know either syntax is wrong or how am passing the object it's not the correct way, I tried different ways but still not working

there is my front-end api call :

```
export const addNewText = (text, pdfFile, xlsFile) => (dispatch) => {
const data = {
    text,pdfFile,xlsFile
}
axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/text/',
    data: data,
    headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
});
```

}

this is my back-end controller function :

```
@PostMapping("/")
public String addText(@RequestBody Text text,@RequestParam("pdfFile") MultipartFile 
pdfFile,@RequestParam("xlsFile") MultipartFile xlsFile) {

      System.out.println("========>"+text.getTitre());

    return "succes";
}
```

I was just testing to print the text title from the object that I passed through that post request but it's always null

Comment: Rest API should consumes = {"multipart/form-data"} and also use @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file

Comment: @dassum what about the text entity what annotation should i put ? and is the way i passed the object to the api request is the correct way or not ?

Comment: Please update headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" 
    }

Comment: even with that content type its still not working

Answer (score 0):

Rest API should be updated as below

```
@PostMapping("/",consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
public String addText(@RequestPart Text text,@RequestPart("pdfFile") MultipartFile 
pdfFile,@RequestPart("xlsFile") MultipartFile xlsFile) {
      System.out.println("========>"+text.getTitre());
    return "succes";
}
```

And UI code should be updated as below

```
axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/text/',
    data: data,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    }
});
```

Comment: it gives me this error  "the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found"

Comment: did you use formData ?